# Passport - Azure AD - Application is not supported for this API version

Tags: passport.js, adal

When I use NPM package "passport-azure-ad" to try and connect to Azure AD, I am getting the error below. I have successfully connected to Facebook, Google, and MSFT Live, successfully, but cannot figure out why Azure AD doesn't like my configuration.

What does this error mean???

Error:

```
Application xxx is not supported for this API version.
```

I've looked at quite a few articles and the GitHub repo, but each is slightly different, and doesn't make it clear which options are required.

https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApi-Nodejs/blob/master/node-server/app.js
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-node-webapp-openidconnect/blob/master/app.js

Here's my configuration:

```
var OIDCStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').OIDCStrategy;

var WINDOWS_AD_CLIENT_ID = "xxxx"
var WINDOWS_AD_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxx"

passport.use(new OIDCStrategy({
        callbackURL: "/dealer/auth/azuread/callback"
        , realm: 'xxxxx' //tenant Id
        , clientID: WINDOWS_AD_CLIENT_ID
        , clientSecret: WINDOWS_AD_CLIENT_SECRET
        , identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'
        //, tenantName: 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com'
        //, policyName: 'B2C_1_DealerSignin'
        //, validateIssuer: true
        //, audience: 'http://localhost:3000/dealer'
        //oidcIssuer: config.creds.issuer,
        , skipUserProfile: true // for AzureAD should be set to true.
        , responseType: 'id_token' // for login only flows use id_token. For accessing resources use `id_token code`
        , responseMode: 'form_post' // For login only flows we should have token passed back to us in a POST
        //scope: ['email', 'profile'] // additional scopes you may wish to pass
    },
    function(iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) {
        console.log("Windows AD Profile retrieved")
        return done(null, profile);
    }
));
```

And Routes:

```
router.get('/auth/azuread',
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { scope: 'email profile' }),
    function(){
        console.log("Azure AD endpoint invoked.")
    });

router.post('/auth/azuread/callback',
    function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Azure AD Auth callback is invoked")
        next()
    },
    passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect'),
    function(req, res) {
        console.log("Azure AD Auth callback is finished")
        res.redirect('/dealer');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue whenever I created my application under:

```
Portal.Azure.com -> Azure AD -> App Registrations
```

or the equivalent on the Classic Portal.

I had to create my app under:

```
apps.dev.microsoft.com
```

For it to work. Hopefully this helps someone else.